# kubernetes pods went down when iptables changed

Tags: kubernetes

When I modified the iptables on the host，the k8s pods went down. seems like communication within cluster blocked. pod status turned into ContainerCreating.
I just want to do a simple ip white list like below.

iptables -A INPUT -s 10.xxx.4.0/24 -p all -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT

Then I delete the reject item in the iptables,pods went running again.
I just want to know how to do a simple ip white list on a host and Not affecting k8s pods running?

the events:
[image]!

Comment: Hi, can you please avoid placing an images, and place code or quote itself? It`s more readable when you do that. When you say "do a simple ip while list like below", you mean that this is the actual command that you actually used? Can you describe the pod and update question with the events? What CNI you deployed in your cluster? What CIDR have you specified for the network?

Comment: YES, it was the actual command i used. 10.xxx.4.0/24 was the network segment of the kubernete cluster. I have described again and update the question the events. I'm a Java developer, and I just know little about how kubernete works. thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you bootstrap your cluster? Is it minikube or kubeadm? Can you list your pod with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -owide`? You are rejecting not a single IP but entire subnet. I assume it could be the same as your pods are using and that is whey there are crashing.

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.10.0/24 -p all -j ACCEPT ，   
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.121.190.0/24 -p all -j ACCEPT ，   
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.220.0.0/16 -p all -j ACCEPT ，   
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT ，

Above are the atual commands I used to whitelist ips.Then I use the command u gave to me to check the CIDR.
It showed like '10.220.64.0/24 10.220.66.0/24'. Still dont know what caused this problem.

Comment: Thx! May i know what is your desired state with using iptables? From what are you trying to protect your cluster? Kubernetes  uses iptables to control the network connections between pods (and between nodes), handling many of the networking and port forwarding rules. With the last command you are actually not allowing him to do that.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to leave only one network segment(172.16.10.0/24) to connect to the cluster. I'm a java developer and not so familiar with kubernetes, maybe I need to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes uses iptables to control the network connections between pods (and between nodes), handling many of the networking and port forwarding rules. With the `iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT`  you are actually not allowing him to do that.

Taken from the [understanding kubernestes networking model article](https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/understanding-kubernetes-networking-model/):

> In Kubernetes, iptables rules are configured by the kube-proxy controller that watches the Kubernetes API server for changes. When a change to a Service or Pod updates the virtual IP address of the Service or the IP address of a Pod, iptables rules are updated to correctly route traffic directed at a Service to a backing Pod. The iptables rules watch for traffic destined for a Service’s virtual IP and, on a match, a random Pod IP address is selected from the set of available Pods and the iptables rule changes the packet’s destination IP address from the Service’s virtual IP to the IP of the selected Pod. As Pods come up or down, the iptables ruleset is updated to reflect the changing state of the cluster. Put another way, iptables has done load-balancing on the machine to take traffic directed to a service’s IP to an actual pod’s IP.

---

To secure cluster its better to put all custom rules on the gateway([ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_delivery_controller)) or into cloud  [security groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/). Cluster security level can be handled via  [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/), [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/),  [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)  and others.

Kubernetes has also a good article about  [Securing a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/) and github guide with [best practices about kubernestes security](https://github.com/freach/kubernetes-security-best-practice).